# How can I import archive.pst on flash drive into gmail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, pst

I have archived Outlook 2003 messages on a flash drive, archive.pst. I no longer have access to a computer with any version of Outlook. I need to get those messages into a basic gmail account. Is that possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [Microsoft migration tool](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/outlookmigration).  This should let you import from a PST file directly; guide [here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=153980&rd=1).

Comment: Thanks Geoff. Unfortunately, I'm on a restricted computer that doesn't allow access to programs, and I don't have Google Apps. I just have a flash drive with the pst file and access to my basic gmail account. :>(

Comment: @Alan - What you want to do is not possible without a third-party program.  The simplest solution is to use the mail program built into Windows ( you don't indicate what version ) and use third-party mail to import that messages.  Once you do that you figure the built-in mail program and transfer the email.  Thunderbird will import the messages also.